# Как привязать CWebUser и модель User

Tags: framework, php, yii, mvc

Как связать Yii:app()->user с моделью User. 
Например, чтобы получить экземпляр модели User, нужно вызывать следующий метод:

```
Yii:app()->user->getUser()
```

Например, я хочу получить E-mail авторизованного пользователя:

```
Yii:app()->user->getUser()-email;
```

Некоторый материал взят из: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/80/add-information-to-yii-app-user-by-extending-cwebuser-better-version/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете в Вашем **UserIdentity** после успешной проверки пароля, установить все данные пользователя:

```
foreach($user as $k => $v)
{
  $this->setState($k, $v);
}
```

После этого доступны все поля по:

```
Yii::app()->user->email
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен.
Нужно в UserIdentity установить нужное нам поле:

```
$this->setState('email',$this->email);
```

И потом его спокойно получать через:

```
Yii::app()->user->getState('email');
```

Comment: Небольшое занудство:
Обращение к данным можно осуществлять попросту 

Yii::app()->user->email;